# JMeter use of variables (CSV Data Set)

Tags: jmeter

I have a question on the visibility scope of variables. I have two thread groups, each with CSV file and controller containing http request steps, testing the application.

```
Thread Group1
    CSV file1
    Controller1
        Test Steps1
Thread Group2
    CSV file2
    Controller2
        Test Steps2
```

Both Controllers use the values in each Thread Group's CSV file just fine. However, I then want to make a Thread Group Combined containing both Controller1 and Controller2

```
Thread Group Combined
    CSV file1
    CSV file2
    Controller1
        Test Steps1
    Controller2
        Test Steps2
```

The problem is that the CSV files both use the same variable name, therefore I guess Controller1 and Controller2 don't know which CSV file to use. I still want Controller1 to use CSV file1 and Controller2 to use CSV2. Will a setup like this work?

```
Thread Group Combined
    Controller1
        CSV file1
        Test Steps1
    Controller2
        CSV file2
        Test Steps2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 'Config Element' - It does not matter where you place it - they are like Global variables (Test Plan Scope). **They get initialized before your test starts** .

Lets assume i have a set up like this.

```
Thread Group 1
     User Defined Variable (A=100)

Thread Group 2
     User Defined Variable (A=150)
```

Now If i run this test - Under Thread Group 1 - If i try to print the value of A, it would be 150. This is because - Scope of these variables are not within Thread Groups - they are global variables.

For this setup,

```
Thread Group 1

Thread Group 2
     User Defined Variable (A=150)
```

Now If i run this test - Under Thread Group 1 - If i try to print the value of A, it would still be 150 even if i do not have User Defined Variables under Thread Group 1.

However - variables you create with Beanshell etc have 'Thread scope'.

So, you might want to use unique variables accordingly.